# Lenovo X1 - HDMI Output

Tags: 12.04, video, hdmi, output

I'm facing problems with HDMI output to my TV (Ölevia HD-TV). When I connect HDMI cable computer / tv I can see the detect each other, and on display configuration I can see the other display, but for some reason it doesn't work. On TV I can see the message "Invalid Format".

```
lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; uname -a; sudo dmidecode -t 1
[sudo] password for ru: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux laptop_ru 3.2.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:28:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 1291A11
    Version: ThinkPad X1
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Not Specified
    Family: ThinkPad X1
```

Comment: Could you include some details (link perhaps) on the "Ölevia HD-TV"? The TV may report a corrupt EDID or one with slightly out of the ordinary modes. With the exact model no/type we might be able to find more relevant clues.

Comment: Model: Olevia 232-T12, but I'm able to connect HDMI when on windows, due this reason I think the problem lies on UBUNTU configuration.

Comment: Googling for "Olevia 232-T12" lists all sorts of HDMI issues, from XBox to PCs to media players. Google also directly suggest a firmware upgrade. Did you try that?

Comment: Give output of `xrandr`

Answer (score 0):

Add an HDMI/VGA converter adapter to your setup,convert your hdmi output into VGA so your TV will recognize the format